# Scala Spark convert date to a specific format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date-formatting

I am reading some JSON file into a data frame and I want to convert a field in it into a specific format,  the JSON file has `server_received_time` with the following format as String I want to convert it to be like `yyyy-MM-dd:hh`

```
"server_received_time":"2019-01-26T03:04:36Z"
```

but whatever I tied just returned  `null`

```
   df.select("server_received_time")
.withColumn("tx_date", to_date($"server_received_time", "yyy-MM-dd:hh").cast("timestamp"))
.withColumn("tx_date2", to_timestamp($"server_received_time", "yyy-MM-dd:hh").cast("timestamp"))
.withColumn("tx_date3", to_date(unix_timestamp($"server_received_time", "yyyy-MM-dd:hh").cast("timestamp")))
.withColumn("tx_date4", to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("server_received_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd:hh"), "UTC"))
.withColumn("tx_date5", to_timestamp($"server_received_time","yyyy-MM-dd:hh"))

.show(10, false)

+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|server_received_time|tx_date|tx_date2|tx_date3|tx_date4|tx_date5|
+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
|2019-02-18T16:02:20Z|null   |null    |null    |null    |null    |
+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to have the `server_received_time` in this format `yyyy-MM-dd:hh`

Comment: your server_received_time in specific format that needs to be used to convert string to unix timestamp that can be formatted in various formats later. For .e.g. unix_timestamp($"server_received_time","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_` methods take actual format, not desired output format. To format you have to convert data back to string

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq("2019-02-18T16:02:20Z").toDF("server_received_time")

df.select(date_format(to_timestamp($"server_received_time"), "yyy-MM-dd:hh")).show
// +---------------------------------------------------------------+
// |date_format(to_timestamp(`server_received_time`), yyy-MM-dd:hh)|
// +---------------------------------------------------------------+
// |                                                  2019-02-18:05|
// +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The format is different. This should work as below:

```
df.select(date_format(to_timestamp($"server_received_time", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"), "yyyy-MM-dd:hh").as("custom_date"))
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question , I want to have the server_received_time in this format yyyy-MM-dd:hh